# Error when deleting user in active_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, rails-activerecord

I get the following error when I attempt to delete a user :

```
undefined method `handle_dependency' for #<ActiveRecord::Associations::HasAndBelongsToManyAssociation:0x007fa889b27328>)
```

My User model is:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  rolify
  attr_accessible :user_attributes
  attr_accessible :username, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :role_ids
  has_one :role, :dependent => :destroy

  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  validates_presence_of :username, :email, :password, :case_sensitive => true
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, :case_sensitive => false
  validates_uniqueness_of :username, :case_sensitive => false

  before_create :assign_role

  def assign_role
    self.add_role :user if self.roles.first.nil?
  end

  after_create { |admin| admin.send_reset_password_instructions }

end
```

My Role model is:

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users, :through => :users_roles, :dependent => :destroy
  belongs_to :resource, :polymorphic => true
  attr_accessible :role_attributes
  resourcify
  scopify
end
```

Am I doing something wrong? The `handle_dependency` method doesn't seem to exist. Will greatly appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I can't explain that specific error, but it looks like there is some confusion about rolify's macro methods do. Here is some background:

`rolify` establishes a `has_and_belongs_to_many` between the User and Role models. So the `has_one` call in your User model is unnecessary and might be causing problems.

`resourcify` is used to indicate that users can have one or more roles with respect to a given class or instances of that class. Users don't have roles with respect to Roles, they have roles with respect to Posts or Articles or whatever. So the `resourcify` call in your Role model is very likely causing a problem. You need to call `resourcify` in the class for the models to which you are trying to restrict access.

Comment: Hi Steve. Thanks for the response. I added resourcify to Role as I wanted the admin role to be able to change a user's role but now that I think about it, the change is in user_role and not Role itself so I can remove that.

I did try out the changes you suggested but I still get the same error. Is there any way I can override the method call and handle it myself?

Comment: I wondered if it was something like that. If it were me I would just have a generic role (not scoped to a resource) and explicitly check that the user had that role before allowing them to change roles, but there probably are more elegant ways to handle it and more complicated use cases that would make that hard manage.

Answer (score 0):

I've investigated this as I'm trying to `rolify` and `resourcify` a model other than `User` or `Role`.  I don't have a clear answer but I can provide what I've found. If nothing else, make sure you have the latest version of rolify ("bundle update rolify").

I've answered a similar issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23003808/1011746

Unfortunately, I've been unable to figure out how the `:roles` association is being overwritten in your code. It's possible that it's something other than `:roles` that is being overwritten but I haven't located it.

This isn't much of an answer but I hope it points in the right direction.